# Translate Gyroscope readings to bearing in degrees

Tags: android, rotation, gyroscope, dead-reckoning, inertial-navigation

I am trying to find the angle of rotation of a car while it makes a turn using Gyroscope from an Android device. So imagine a car is travelling in a bearing of angle 168 and makes a right turn on a road. Now I need to calculate the new heading or bearing angle just using Gyroscope. But the values I receive are in radians/sec. I tried integrating these values over the time period dT. But these values are not even close to the actual angles. I thought the rotation are in reference to the device, and I tried to convert the values to the real World coordinates. But I didnt get a good algorithm for that.

Can someone help me or point to the right resources to solve this issue?

EDIT:
I forgot to mention in the question, I am trying to do this without GPS, (in the scenario when GPS fails.) And I am trying to avoid Sensor fusion as I am planning to use only Gyroscope as I am looking for a solution that could run even out of Android platform. I am even talking to the OBD to get the actual speed of the vehicle. So I am just trying to collect Gyroscope data from any client and process it at the back end and determine just the turning of a vehicle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [rotation vector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR) see description [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEvent.html#values) (API level 9).
This thing is using something called [sensor fusion](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C7JQ7Rpwn2k) to get good quality information about phone orientation relative to earth and magnetic north.
You can also calculate derivate of GPS position to estimate car turn direction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am sorry, I forgot to mention in the question, I am trying to do this without GPS, (in the scenario when GPS fails.) And I am trying to avoid Sensor fusion as I am planning to use only Gyroscope as I am looking for a solution that could run even out of Android platform.

Comment: in this case why are you using gyroscope? Magnetometer is better.

Comment: I tried Magnetometer, but it becomes unreliable in the cities with tall buildings, or while driving by bridges where there are lot of magnetic flux.